# Undefined method error when accessing a field inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My model looks like this

```
require 'bcrypt'

class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :encrypt_password

  # some validations and other methods




  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_encrypted = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end


  def self.authenticate(hash)
    auth = where(provider: 'email', email: hash[:email])
    if auth and auth.password_encrypted == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(hash[:password], auth.password_salt)
      auth
    else
      nil
    end
  end

end
```

but when in my controller I call `Authorization.authenticate(hash)` with the hash given by `params.permit(:email, :password)` I get undefined method `password_encrypted' when it actually exists.

Comment: probably `where(provider: 'email', email: hash[:email])` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `authenticate` class method is returning a relation instead of an instance, which is why your instance variables are not available.

You'll have to modify the first line of your authenticate method to look something like so:

```
auth = where(provider: 'email', email: hash[:email]).first
```

Or maybe

```
auth = find_by(provider: 'email', email: hash[:email])
```

Something along those lines to make sure you're dealing with an instance of `Authorization` rather than the relation returned by the `where` call (even if it's only returning one record).